# Can we add only necessary ciphers for an Azure Redis Cache hosted in a Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-redis-cache

I have hosted my Azure Redis Cache inside a Virtual Network and our penetration testing team has suggested to allow required Cipher suites as per the company norms. Is it possible to alter the cipher suites.

Comment: Currently, no. But why would you care if you're not exposing a public endpoint? Why would you even use TLS inside a VNET? Are you working under an Assume Breach model?

Comment: Please ignore the TLS part it is the issue with Web application i have restricted it now. So my only question now will be on altering cipher suites.